# GetComponent в FixedUpdate()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я проверяю землю под игроком.

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _isCeiled = isCeiled();
        _isGrounded = isGrounded();
    }

    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        return transform.Find("GroundCheck").GetComponent<GroundCheck>()._isGrounded;
    }
```

Я читал, что GetComponent лучше не использовать в FixedUpdate(), а в данном случае это считается?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А почему должно не считаться?

Comment: Выносите `GetComponent` куда-нибудь вне апдейта. В инициализации какие-нибудь.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: GetComponent не стоит использовать в Update, а Find вообще нельзя использовать, тем более в Update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обращение всё так же в том же методе, только через посредника.

ЗЫ: поиск через `Find` тоже убивает производительность.